# How do I make a child not show the parent?

Tags: html, css

I have a list that I am placing a div inside it and don't want to show the list where the `div` is at.  Here is the list

```
<div class="daily-view">
    <ul class="hours">
        <li>
            <div class="appt">Jason Hamm</div>
            <div class="lines"></div>
            <div class="lines"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the styles for the list:

```
.daily-view .hours {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.daily-view .lines {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 20px;
}
.appt {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I want the `appt` class to not show anything that is behind it.  Right now it shows up like this:

[image]

You can see the background line going through the div.  I tried `z-index`, but that didn't work.  How would I do this?

Comment: Why are you putting it in that div at all if you want it to appear somewhere else?

Comment: div and li and then li is not allowed its not valid html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `background: #fff` to your `.appt` container.

http://jsfiddle.net/furudh0g/